# Server client connection recovering

Tags: raspbian, networking

I have Sever/Client sending data back and forth, everything works fine, until the client looses connection and tries to reconnect. When I run the project in the coding windows I can disconnect any client or server and it will reconnect, but when I run it in crontab the server clients reconnect when server is rebooted. but when client is rebooted it will not reconnect. How can I get a error report why that is happening? or why will it work when running from Thonny or Greany and not from crontab? I have a 30 sec. sleep at crontab reboot command.

Server Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import threading
import pygame.mixer
import automationhat
import datetime
from datetime import date
import time
import socket
...

time.sleep(10)
class ButtonServer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, channel, serverIP, serverPort):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.channel = channel
        self.ServIP = serverIP
        self.ServPort = serverPort
        self.conn = ""
        self.Addr = ""
        self.serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.serv.bind((serverIP,serverPort))
        self.serv.listen(5)
        self.ClientHasData = False
        self.ClientConnected = False
        self.BellButtonOne = -1
        self.BellButtonTwo = -1
        self.BellButtonThree = -1
        self.deamon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.conn, self.addr = self.serv.accept()
            from_client = ''

            self.ClientHasData = True
            while self.ClientHasData:
                from_client = ''
                data = self.conn.recv(4096)

                if not data: self.ClientHasData = False

                from_client = data.decode()

                if from_client == "Input 1 On":
                    self.BellButtonOne = 1
                if from_client == "Input 1 Off":
                    self.BellButtonOne = 0

                if from_client == "Input 2 On":
                    self.BellButtonTwo = 1
                if from_client == "Input 2 Off":
                    self.BellButtonTwo = 0

                if from_client == "Input 3 On":
                    self.BellButtonThree = 1
                if from_client == "Input 3 Off":
                    self.BellButtonThree = 0

                if from_client == "Client Connected":
                    sc1.play(snd1)
            self.conn.close()

B8 = ButtonServer(36,"123.456.789.123",12345)

sc1.play(snd1)
playDoing = False

DinnerBellNo = 0
while True:
    if not B8: B8.start
...
```

Client Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import automationhat
import time
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = "123.456.789.123"
port = 12345

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        client.connect((host,port))
        break
    except:
        print()
print("Connected")

client.send("Client Connected".encode())

while True:
    if automationhat.input.one.is_on():
        client.send("Input 1 On".encode())
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if automationhat.input.one.is_off():
            client.send("Input 1 Off".encode())

    if automationhat.input.two.is_on():
        client.send("Input 2 On".encode())
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if automationhat.input.two.is_off():
            client.send("Input 2 Off".encode())

    if automationhat.input.three.is_on():
        client.send("Input 3 On".encode())
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if automationhat.input.three.is_off():
            client.send("Input 3 Off".encode())


    #Handle Server being disconnected.
    try:
        client.send("Connect Test!".encode())
    except:
        print ("Disconnecting")
        client.close()
        print ("Disconnected")
        while True: 
            try:
                client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                client.connect((host,port))
                print ("Connected")
                client.send("Client Connected".encode())
                break
            except Exception as e:
                time.sleep(1)
client.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote my code so the connection is make when needed. which fix a few other problems for me.

Only needed to rewrite the client side code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import automationhat
import time
import socket, sys

def sendMessage(msg):
    try:
        print(msg)
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        host = "123.456.789.123"
        port = 12345
        s.connect((host, port))
        s.send(msg.encode())
        print("Message sent")
        from_server = s.recv(4096)
        s.close()
    except:
        print(sys.exc_info()[0])

sendMessage("Client Connected")

while True:
    if automationhat.input.one.is_on():
        sendMessage("Input 1 On")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if automationhat.input.one.is_off():
            sendMessage("Input 1 Off")

    if automationhat.input.two.is_on():
        sendMessage("Input 2 On")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if automationhat.input.two.is_off():
            sendMessage("Input 2 Off")

    if automationhat.input.three.is_on():
        sendMessage("Input 3 On")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if automationhat.input.three.is_off():
            sendMessage("Input 3 Off")
```

Comment: Please accept your answer with a click on the tick on the left side. This will finish the question and it will not pop up again after months.